# change python to ruby, very basic

Tags: python, ruby

I am not familiar with ruby, and I want to change my python code into ruby for an art project, Here are my broken ruby script, I know "split" function is the same, and I am not sure about how to get one part of an array in ruby. I feel very appreciated if someone can help me out right now.

```
new = line.split(" ")
lala = [w for w in new if len(new)>=4]
newone = lala[1..6].join(" ") + "\n" + lala[6...].join(" ")
```

The initial python code

```
new = line.split(" ")

lala = [w for w in new if len(new)>=4]

newone = (" ").join(lala[1:6]) +"\n" +(" ").join(lala[6:])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
words = line.split(" ")
s = words.select {|w| words.length >=4}
result = s[1...6].join(" ") + "\n" + s[6..-1].join(" ")
```

Comment: `[6:]`'s equivalent ruby version will be: `[6..-1]`.